# If X ist not Banach are weak* compact sets always norm bounded

Tags: functional-analysis

A subset of the norm dual of a normed
space is weak* compact if and only if it is weak* closed and norm bounded.

This is stated without a proof in:

Infinite Dimensional Analysis
A Hitchhiker's Guide

Authors: Aliprantis, Charalambos D., Border, Kim 
Page 235 6.21.

I know that this is true for Banach spaces and one direction from weak* closed and norm bounded to weak* compact is also true.
But I´m not sure if a subset of of the norm dual which is weak* compact is also norm bounded.

If not does exist a counterexample?

Comment: @ David C.Ullrich can u elaborate this? I tried it myself like: weak* compact sets are weak* bounded  hence pointwise bounded but for employing UBP we need that X is a Banach space. Am I missing something?

Comment: @WoolierThanThou: The uniform boundedness principle isn't valid when $X$ is not complete.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou: But your sequence $x_n$ lives in $X^*$, not in $X$.

Answer (score 4):

Meanwhile I think I found a counterexample

Let $X= c_{00}$ the space of finitly supportet sequences endowed with the sup norm and define for $m\in \mathbb{N}$

$$
\delta_m: c_{00}\to \mathbb{R}; \delta_m((a_n)_n) = ma_m.
$$
Then $(\delta_m)_m\subset X'$ converges weakly* to $0$.
Hence $\{\delta_m:m\in \mathbb{N}\}\cup \{0\}$ is weak* compact since X' endowed with the weak* topology is a hausdorff TVS.
But clearly $\{\delta_m:m\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is not norm bounded 
since for $m\in \mathbb{N}$
$$
||\delta_m||_{op}=m.
$$